# DateTime.ParseExact not parsing date correctly in c#

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I have a string date in yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt format and I want to convert it to date time with same format.

Below is code in c#,

```
dates.ToList().ForEach(i =>
{
    var schedule = new Schedule();
    string date = schedule.GetNextValidDate(i);  //returns 2016-03-23 01:00:00 PM
    i.NextValidDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(schedule.GetNextValidDate(i), "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); // returns 3/23/2016 1:00:00 PM
}
```

GetNextValidDate returns a string "2016-03-23 01:00:00 PM" and I want to convert it to a datetime with same format.

How do I do that?

Comment: 'not working' how? Do you get an exception?

Comment: no it returns date in wrong format.

Comment: I think you are confusing a value displayed by the debugger with the value actually being stored. A `DateTime` is just a number, internally. You can format it any different number of ways. The debugger just happens to display it a certain way, for convenience's sake. If you want it to be formatted, output it to a string using the appropriate `ToString()` parameters.

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot I'm assuming his code implies that GetNextValidDate returns a string, though. Otherwise I assume that wouldn't even compile.

Comment: what does `GetNextValidDate` do?

Comment: @Nyerguds Yes but he is parsing it and storing it in `i.NextValidDateTime`, *apparently* as a `DateTime`

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot  Oh. You mean his final result _after_ the parsing. Right, sorry. AMeh, what _does_ it give for that example?

Comment: shouldn't `GetNextValidDate` return a `DateTime`?

Comment: we're going to need a [mcve]. like how is it getting to the jquery layer?

Comment: I wanted to get a date in a specific format so I changed the return type to string

Comment: `DateTime`s have no specific formatting

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to rendering to the date, try this:

```
foreach(DateTime d in dates)
{
    string DateString = d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");

    //Do something with the string called, DateString

}
```